# Add input box where the user can enter a number from 1 to 6

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm creating a dice roller app and need to add a function where the user can enter a number from 1 to 6. If the generated dice number is the same as the number in the box, then display Congratulations.

I already have the main function - the app contains a button that when clicked, generates a random number from 0-6.

```
public void on_button_click(View view) {

    TextView tv = this.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);

    Random r = new Random();
    int bound;
    int number = r.nextInt( 6);

    tv.setText(Integer.toString(number)) ;
}
```

The above is what I already have for the random number generator button. I'm hoping that the end result will be the user can input a number then if the random number is the same as the number that the user inputs, there's a text saying congratulations

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track.  Just compare the value in the numberTextView with whatever the user entered in the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't generate a number from 0 to 6, since dice are numbered from 1 to 6. So change the line

```
 int number = r.nextInt(6);
```

to

```
 int number = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
```

Then to see if the die number matches what the user entered, do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EditText userNumber;
    Button submitButton;
    userNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNumber);
    submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void on_button_click(View view) {
          TextView tv = this.findViewById(R.id.numberTextView);
          Random r = new Random();
          int number = r.nextInt(6 - 1) + 1;
          tv.setText(Integer.toString(number));
          try {
             int theNumber = Integer.valueOf(userNumber.getText().toString());
             if (theNumber < 1 || theNumber > 6)
                 // Tell user the number was out of range
             if (number == theNumber)
                Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this, "Congratulations!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          catch (Exception er) {
             Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this, er.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
       }
    });
}
```